# Get hierarchical data is SQL SERVER with fallback logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the below schema

```
dbo.Cultures (Id, CultureCode, ParentId)
```

- Culture table stores the data in the parent-child relationship.
  Suppose we have below demo data

### [image]

```
         5         es-ES       3
```

Now I have another table which stores the multilingual data for the different cultures.
Schema for the table is as following

```
dbo.LangData(KeyName, CultureId, Value)
```

here cultureId is the foreign key of dbo.Cultures table.

Suppose this table has following data

---

[image]

Now I require to fetch the data for all the cultures which are in the **Culture** table and the corresponding value column in the **LangData** table.
 The culture Ids which are not in the LangData table, for those the **Value** column will the value of the corresponding parent culture Id columns value. I.e. Data will be retrieved using fallback logic

### E.g. For the above values the Result set will be following.

[image]

```
         5  es-ES     Colour_IN
```

Here for de-DE data is missing in LangData so it's value will be the data in it's parent culture i.e. en-IN, if in case data also not found in en-IN then it will pick the data of it's parent en-US.

**Tried Soloution**
  First I fetch the culture hierarchy using CTE

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetCultureHierarchyAll] () 
RETURNS @hierarchyResult TABLE(RowNo INT, CultureId INT, ParentCultureId INT) 
AS 
BEGIN
 WITH CultureHierarchy_CTE(RowNo, CultureId, ParentCultureId) 
           AS (             
              SELECT 1, 
                     Id, 
                     ParentId 
              FROM   [dbo].Cultures 
               UNION ALL 
               SELECT RowNo + 1, 
                      ou.Id, 
                      ou.ParentId 
               FROM   [dbo].Cultures ou 
                      JOIN CultureHierarchy_CTE cte 
                      ON ou.Id = cte.ParentCultureId
                      )

 -- inserting desired records into table and returning
   INSERT INTO @hierarchyResult (RowNo,CultureId,ParentCultureId )
   SELECT RowNo, CultureId , ParentCultureId FROM CultureHierarchy_CTE

    RETURN;
END
```

This will return the hierarchy of the all the cultures
Now I attempted to apply join of the result set with the LangData table,

```
   DECLARE @cultureHierarchy AS TABLE(
    RowNumber INT,
    CultureId INT,
    ParentCultureId INT
    )
    --SELECT * FROM master.Cultures
     ----Get and store culture hierarchy
     INSERT INTO @cultureHierarchy
     SELECT RowNo, CultureId, ParentCultureId
     FROM  ufnGetCultureHierarchyAll()

     SELECT c.Code AS [CultureCode],
    c.CultureId AS [CultureId],
    rv.Value
    FROM dbo.LangData rv WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN @cultureHierarchy c ON rv.CultureId = c.CultureId
  END
```

but it is not working. 
  Is someone have any Idea regarding same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using Itzik Ben-Gan's hierarchy model. If you can extend the dbo.Cultures table with Hierarchy, Lvl and Root columns and index on Hierarchy, query will be faster. It has to be rewrited in that case though.

```
drop table if exists dbo.Cultures;

create table dbo.Cultures (
    ID int
    , Code varchar(50)
    , ParentID int
);

insert into dbo.Cultures (ID, Code, ParentID)
values (1, 'en-US', null), (2, 'en-IN', 1), (3, 'de-DE', 2), (4, 'hi-HI', 2)


drop table if exists dbo.LangData;

create table dbo.LangData (
    KeyName varchar(100)
    , CultureID int
    , Value varchar(100)
);

insert into dbo.LangData (KeyName, CultureID, Value)
values ('lblColourName', 1, 'Color'), ('lblColourName', 2, 'Colour-IN');

with cteCultures as (
    select
        c.ID, c.Code, c.ParentID, 0 as Lvl
        , convert(varchar(max), '.' + CONVERT(varchar(50), c.ID) + '.') as Hierarchy
        , c.ID as Root
    from dbo.Cultures c
    where c.ParentID is null
    union all
    select
        c.ID, c.Code, c.ParentID, cc.Lvl + 1 as Lvl
        , cc.Hierarchy + convert(varchar(50), c.ID) + '.' as Hierarchy
        , cc.Root as Root
    from dbo.Cultures c
        inner join cteCultures cc on c.ParentID = cc.ID
)
select
    ccr.ID
    , ccr.Code
    , coalesce(ld.Value, ld2.Value) as Value
from cteCultures ccr
    left join dbo.LangData ld on ccr.ID = ld.CultureID
    outer apply (
            select
                top (1) tcc.ID
            from cteCultures tcc
                inner join dbo.LangData tld on tcc.ID = tld.CultureID
            where ld.KeyName is null
                and ccr.Hierarchy like tcc.Hierarchy + '%'
                and ccr.Hierarchy <> tcc.Hierarchy
            order by tcc.Lvl desc
    ) tt
    left join dbo.LangData ld2 on tt.ID = ld2.CultureID
```

Comment: Hi Dean, Thanks for the solution but this will not produce the desired result in multilevel hierarchy of culture, suppose if I insert one more row in the Cultures table as - insert into dbo.Cultures (ID, Code, ParentID)
values (5, 'es-ES', 3). This means the de-DE is the parent of es-ES culture and en-IN is the parent of de-DE and en-US is the parent of en-IN. So in this 3 level hierarchy if data is missing in LangData table for newly inserted es-ES culture then it should be picked from parent de-DE and for de-DE is also missing then from en-IN, means fallback in culture hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

We just build your hierarchy (SEQ and Lvl are optional) and then perform TWO left joins in concert with a Coalesce().

**Example**

```
Declare @Cultures table (id int,ParentId  int,Code varchar(50))
Insert into @Cultures values 
 ( 1, NULL,'en-US')
,( 2, 1   ,'en-IN')
,( 3, 2   ,'de-DE')
,( 4, 2   ,'hi-HI')

Declare @LangData table (keyName varchar(50),CultureId int,Value varchar(50))
Insert Into @LangData values
 ('lblColourName',1,'Color')
,('lblColourName',2,'Color_IN')


;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by Code) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,ParentId 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Code 
      From   @Cultures 
      Where  ParentId is null
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Code)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.ParentId 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Code 
      From   @Cultures r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentId  = p.ID)
Select CultureId = A.ID
      ,A.Code
      ,Value  = Coalesce(C.Value,B.Value)
 From cteP A
 Left Join @LangData B on (A.ParentId=B.CultureId)
 Left Join @LangData C on (A.Id=C.CultureId)
 Order By Seq
```

**Returns**

```
CultureId   Code    Value
1           en-US   Color
2           en-IN   Color_IN
3           de-DE   Color_IN
4           hi-HI   Color_IN
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the solution but this will not produce the desired result in multilevel culture hierarchy, suppose if I insert one more row in the Cultures table as - insert into dbo.Cultures (ID, Code, ParentID)
values (5, 'es-ES', 3). This means the de-DE is the parent of es-ES and en-IN is the parent of de-DE and en-US is the parent of en-IN. So in this 3 level hierarchy if data is missing in LangData table for es-ES culture then it should be picked from parent de-DE and if for de-DE is also missing then from en-IN, . This solution will return Null for es-ES. I have updated question